# Получение данных по API и хранение в redux. React Js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

Доброго времени суток.

У меня вопрос по правильной организации кода.

Задача такая. Получить данных по API, модифицировать (добавить флаги) записать их в хранилище и после чего их использовать.

Стек что использую: React Js, Redux, ts.

Т.к. страниц на сайте не будет, данные подтягивать нужно будет сразу с API. Правильно ли я сделаю, что обращение к API у меня будет не в компоненте, а напрямую из редюсера redux ? Если да, то как сделать так, чтобы обращение сработало сразу при старте redux? В какой момент делать обращение к API?

Пример кода редюсера:

```
import {ActionCreator, Reducer} from "redux";

export type RootState = {
    posts: object
}

const initialState = {
    posts: []
}

const POSTS = 'ANIME_POSTS'

type UpdateAnimePosts = {
    type: typeof POSTS
    posts: object
}

export const updatePosts: ActionCreator<UpdatePosts> = (posts) => ({
    type: POSTS,
    posts
})


export const rootReducer: Reducer<RootState> = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case POSTS:
            return {
                ...state,
                posts: action.posts
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понятно утверждение "страниц на сайте не будет".
Использование React.js подразумевает выполнение javascript кода в браузере пользователя, который перешел на ваш сайт.

Когда пользователь переходит на ваш сайт, react.js должен отобразить какую-то разметку, в терминах реакта - компонент.
При взаимодействии с какой-либо кнопкой или при маунте компонента должен выполниться запрос к вашему API.

При получении респонса должен быть задиспатчен экшен updatePosts, в payload к которому вы передадите данные из респонса.
Редьюсер, получив ваш экшен в соответствующем кейсе, может полученный action.payload необходимым образом видоизменить и записать в state.

Далее необходимо создать селектор, отдающий данные из state, которые с помощью useSelector будут получены в компоненте, в котором их необходимо отобразить.

Обобщая, организация потока данных выглядит так:
открылась страница -> сделали запрос к API -> после получения респонса задиспатчили экшен -> редьюсер получил экшен с данными и положил их в стор -> страница с помощью useSelector получила новые данные из стора.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Картина сложилась. 
Но у меня остался вопрос, извините заранее если он глупый. 
>> сделали запрос к API. 


>>  При взаимодействии с какой-либо кнопкой или при маунте компонента должен выполниться запрос к вашему API.



Получается, КОМПАНЕНТ должен сделать запрос и задиспачить экшен?

Comment: Да. Внутри компонента вы можете описать хук

    useEffect(() => {
        doRequest().then((res) => dispatch(myAction(res)))
    }, []);

таким образом при маунте компонента будет сделан запрос и вызван экшен с данными из респонса.

Comment: У меня возник вопрос. В какой момент можно будет модифицировать полученные данные? Считается ли хорошим тоном модифицировать данные в редюсире? Или в стор должны попасть сразу модифицированные данные (модифицировать сразу после получения в компоненте) ?

Comment: Модифицировать данные полученные от вашего API нужно в редьюсере. Процесс приведения данных полученных от API к тому виду, в котором ими удобно пользоваться в рамках сущностей frontend приложения, называется нормализацией. Так же добавлять какие-то флаги/дополнительные поля так же нужно в редьюсере.